# GetCustomAttribute Equivalent in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.0

I am using a sample project for Entity Framework Audit Trail from [here](https://github.com/bilal-fazlani/tracker-enabled-dbcontext)

The problem is we are already using .NET 4.0 in our project but this sample is using .NET 4.5.

Can somebody tell me what is the equivalent of `GetCustomAttribute` in .NET 4, 
Below is my code:

```
    private static string ColumnNameFactory(this Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        string columnName = propertyName;
        Type entityType = type.GetEntityType();
        var columnAttribute = entityType.GetProperty(propertyName).GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>(false);
        if (columnAttribute != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnAttribute.Name))
        {
            columnName = columnAttribute.Name;
        }
        return columnName;
    }
```

In this code: `GetCustomAttribute` is not recognized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`MemberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) belongs to the [`CustomAttributeExtensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.customattributeextensions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension class which contains very thin wrappers to [`Attribute.GetCustomAttribute()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.getcustomattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Attribute.GetCustomAttributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.getcustomattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  These wrappers cast the returned `Attribute` to the expected attribute type.  See the reference source here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/CustomAttributeExtensions.cs.